# Redimensionar imagem dinamicamente

Tags: php, javascript

No site da webmotors, as imagens sao redimensionadas dinamicamente...

link: https://image.webmotors.com.br/_fotos/anunciousados/gigante/2018/201804/20180403/ford-fiesta-1.0-mpi-hatch-8v-flex-4p-manual-wmimagem15381473185.jpg?s=fill&w=800&h=300&q=50

no final da imagem temos `.jpg?s=fill&w=800&h=300&q=50`.

Como eu faço isso? e dependendo do tamanho insere a marca d`agua da webmotors...

Qual a biblioteca ou funcao no php, javascript que posso fazer isso? Pode haver a possibilidade de fazer isso via `.htaccess`?

Comment: [GD](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.image.php)?

Comment: Você consegue com isso: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/imagick.resizeimage.php

Comment: Vou estudar as bibliotecas e volto para postar

Comment: Existe outra maneira de ser feito?

Comment: Você pode formatar pelo css, mas a imagem será redimensionada "virtualmente"

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar pelo Imacki